# Modifying jQuery selector in a var

Tags: jquery, selector

I may explained bad, but I didn't know how to describe that, anyway..

I have this var:

```
var d_atributo=$("div.atributo");
```

There's anyway to do select an element child of the mentioned this way?

```
d_atributo.$(" span.example).click(function(){...});
```

I mean that I want to use this var and extend his "definition" on the fly.

Comment: You can just use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***No. You can't do it in your way with default jQuery selector.***

You can do:

```
d_atributo.find("span.example").click(function(){
   // your code
});
```

**OR**

```
d_atributo.children("span.example").click(function(){
   // your code
});
```

**OR**

```
$("span.example", d_atributo).click(function() {
 // your code
});
```

Comment: Upvoted for giving a few different options. Note to OP is that the second option (using children) will behave differently and only find elements that are immediate children of d_attributo

Comment: thankyou so much thecodeparadox!

Answer (score 1):

You could alias `find`:

```
jQuery.fn.$ = jQuery.fn.find;
```

Then it will work:

```
var d_atributo = $("div.atributo");
d_atributo.$("span.example").click(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9rFBS/1/

Comment: I love this answer. (But I would strongly recommend against doing it)

Comment: Heh yea, it's just to keep this interesting :P He asked for "this way" after all

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
d_atributo.find("span.example").click(function(){...});
```

or use `children()` instead of `find()` if you're looking for immediate children

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for the [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
d_atributo.children("span.example").click(function() {
    // ...
});
```